# "Vote to close" button does not get re-enabled if I click too fast

Tags: bug, close-dialog

Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a question
2. Click the "close" link
3. Select "off-topic because..."
4. Click "Programming question", "Vote to close" button is now enabled.
5. Click "Other", button is now disabled
6. Click *fast* on "Programming question" again, button enables but instantly disables again.

What is "fast" clicking you ask? Just press the mouse button for the shortest moment you can. Keeping the mouse button down (for a half second roughly, maybe less) on the option does enable the button without problems.

Firefox 22.

Comment: I can reproduce this in Chrome 28, as well. It appears that the button is briefly enabled, and then almost immediately disabled again. There must be some timer used here that is acting up.

Comment: @Cody yep, the JS code is full with timers. :)

Comment: I don't know if it is just bias from not being a web programmer, but I think of timers as a *huge* hack. Aside from being fragile and easily broken, there is just usually a better way to do things. Maybe not with JS though.

Comment: @CodyGray: I would agree, but doing JavaScript in a cross-browser way (even with jQuery) can be a sink bigger then the Marianas Trench. I would not be surprised if a timer was used to circumvent some stupid, froggy things one or two browsers did with the events.